# Ignore side effect in monadic code

Tags: monad

Is there a standardized notion of something that removes side effects for an element in a monad?

In the case of state monad:

An element `mx : m X` is effectively `mx : S -> X×S` and I would like to turn it into `mx'`:

```
def mx' : m X := fun (s : S) => (fst (mx s), s)
```

i.e. remove the effect of `mx` on the state.

This of course does not make sense for every monad, maybe it makes sense only for state monad. But I can imagine you could use it to suppress writing to a file for example.

So I'm curious if this is a common notion or not.

---

Edit: Also, what should be the abstract definition of such function? My current definition(in Lean 4) is:

```
class IgnoreEffect (m : Type u → Type v) [Monad m]
  ignoreEffect {α} : m α → m α

  bind_ignore_effect {α β} (ma : m α) (mb : m β) : 
    (bind (ignoreEffect ma) λ a => mb) = mb
```

I have a gut feeling there should be an additional law for the case when the value `a` is actually used. I'm unsure how to formulate it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you explain the background and motivation for what you'd like to do?

Comment: This question is almost two years old and I do not even remember what was the exact motivation. I wanted to do automatic differentiation(AD) of monadic code and for that I needed to define what a differentiable monad is. I remember this was part of it but it was dead end. Fortunately, now I have a good definition of differentiable monad and I can successfully run AD on monadic code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a formulation in two steps:

1. There must be a natural transformation $\mathrm{run} : \forall a.\, m\,a\to a$.

The function `run` is a designated "runner" that extracts a value out of a monad.

Note that `run` is *not* necessarily a monad morphism $m\to \mathrm{Id}$, where $\mathrm{Id}$ is the identity monad ($\mathrm{Id} \, a = a$). For instance, the State monad does not have such a monad morphism. Some monads do have a monad morphism of that sort; for example, extracting the first element of a non-empty list. Other monads (for example, the continuation monads) cannot even have a natural transformation of type $\forall a.\,m\,a\to a$.

2. Then we define `ignoreEffect = return . run`.